# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу C#

Tags: c#, pdf, доступ

Делаю парсинг и разделение pdf файла, затем отправляю его на сервер, получаю ошибку, что   Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "C:\Users\source\repos\SM\SMC\bin\Debug\2.pdf", так как этот файл используется другим процессом. Пробовала закрывать в коде документы - не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста

```
private async Task ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(string path)

    {

        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

        string resultPdfText = "";

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfr = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);

        Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        Document.Compress = true;
        doc.Open();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfr.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            resultPdfText += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfr, i);
        }
       
        int j = 0;
      
        string[] sourceText = resultPdfText.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceText.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (sourceText[i].Contains("ИЗВЕЩЕНИЕ"))
            {
                i += 4;
                string dateStr = sourceText[i].Substring(sourceText[i].IndexOf("ПЕРИОД") + 7);

                DateTime date = default;
                date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

                i++;
                string ls = sourceText[i].Trim();
               

                PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

                outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;

                outputDocument.Info.Title = String.Format("Bills_keyField_{0}{1}.pdf", ls, date.ToString("Myyyy"));
                outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

                outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[j]);
                string pdfName = String.Format("Bills_keyField_{0}{1}.pdf", ls, date.ToString("Myyyy"));
                outputDocument.Save(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "outcoming", pdfName));
               
                AddPDFFile(pdfName);
               
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: в какой именно строке ошибка?

Comment: если ошибка на этой строке, то смотрите на предыдущей вы уже открыли файл на чтение:  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfr = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);

Comment: да, тут ошибка. Просто использую две библиотеки, одну для парсинга pdf, другую для разделения pdf, не нашли как можно использовать одну библиотеку

Comment: Открыватели файла Stream умеют принимать для открытия файла или только путь к файлу?

Comment: принимают путь к файлу

Comment: Ну тогда вам надо для каждого свой файл скопировать. Но это странно конечно.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо